# The best way to dynamically resize image using Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a requirement to dynamically generate image sizes on the fly.

I researched a bit and found some solutions:

1. https://serverless.com/blog/dynamic-image-resizing-nodejs/ (however we don't want our S3 bucket to have website configuration as we want to serve it using Cloudfront + OAI)
2. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/resizing-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-aws-cdn-blog/ (lambda@edge is currently in us-east-1 only. We're in a different region and would like the lambda to be in our region.)

---

It seems both solutions do not satisfy our requirements... and I found another solution which uses cloudfront origin groups. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html

I made a minimum working solution:

1. Use S3 as the primary origin
2. Use Api gateway backed by lambda as the secondary origin (to resize the image and save it to S3)

this is my lambda code:

> note that this is just a sample so I hardcoded things a bit. I also don't have any error handling yet.

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async event => {
  console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(event));
  const file = await s3
    .getObject({
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: "image/original/test.png"
    })
    .promise();

  const { data, info } = await sharp(file.Body)
    .resize({ height: 360 })
    .toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: true });

  await s3
    .putObject({
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: "image/360/test.png",
      Body: data,
      ContentType: "image/" + info.format
    })
    .promise();

  return {
    statusCode: 307,
    headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      Location: "https://mycloudfrontdist.com/image/360/test.png"
    }
  };
};
```

This solution works. However, I'm not sure if `origin groups` is an appropriate solution to the problem. Moreover, it's prone to infinite redirects. (e.g. if I made a mistake in the Location field, it would trigger infinite redirects.

### Question

Are there any critical concerns that I miss with that `origin groups` solution? Are there any other alternatives that I should take into account?

Comment: I don't know why second solution isn't satisfying for you, lambda@edge available in all AWS regions which supports lambda, you create it in us-east-1 but it gets replicated to all regions and when you hit the cloudfront edge, the lambda in nearest region triggers.

Comment: Side-note: You could alternatively use services like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/).

Comment: @JamesDean I didn't know that! I tried it using `serverless framework` and it complains that it must in us-east-1. (I didn't bother to research more. silly me.) I'll probably need to create a working sample for that, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That's a good alternative for sure! but it seems this is an opinion-based question.. I'm going to close it..